# Find object having the highest value in JSONB array of objects in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, jsonb

Assuming we have a table where column `data` stores an array of objects.

```
┌────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id │                               data                                    │
├────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ [{"m2": 40.0, "sector": "Office"}, {"m2": 65.0, "room": "Hospital"}]  │
│  2 │ [{"m2": 25.0, "sector": "Cafe"}, {"m2": 120.0, "room": "Office"}]     │
│  3 │ []                                                                    │
└────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I would like to find only these objects, which have the `m2` value the highest.

```
┌────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id │                 data                    │
├────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ {"m2": 65.0, "room": "Hospital"}        │
│  2 │ {"m2": 120.0, "room": "Office"}         │
│  3 │ null                                    │
└────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

PostgreSQL 13.4

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following which uses `json_array_elements` to expand the array before using `row_number` to determine the object with the highest `m2` value.

```sql
select 
    "id", 
    (
       SELECT 
           jr 
       FROM (
           SELECT
               jr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                   ORDER BY jr->'m2' DESC
               ) as rn
           FROM
               jsonb_array_elements("data") as jr
       ) t1
       WHERE rn=1
    ) as "data"
from 
    my_table
```

or simply ordering by `m2` and limiting your result to `1` eg

```sql
select 
    "id", 
    (
       SELECT 
           jr 
       FROM 
           jsonb_array_elements("data") as jr
       ORDER BY 
           jr->'m2' DESC
       LIMIT 1
    ) as "data"
from 
    my_table
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpMEaEwvPDYhz4qAiDwqM6/4)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: is there a difference in performance between the proposed solutions above when we're querying hundreds of thousands of data?

Comment: @davidvnog I recommend the second one as more efficient. If you would like to determine the actual performance difference you may use [`EXPLAIN <insert_query_here>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
with m_d(id, a) as (
    select t1.id, (select json_agg(v.value) from jsonb_array_elements(t1.data::jsonb) v 
    where (v.value -> 'm2')::text::float = (select max((v2.value -> 'm2')::text::float) 
           from jsonb_array_elements(t1.data::jsonb) v2)) from t t1
)
select id, case when json_array_length(a) = 0 then null else a ->> 0 end from m_d;
```